# Vue test utils is updating the component data but not re-rendering the dom

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test the template of my Vue app after making an ajax request which is changing one variable of the component' data. This variable (books) is use to conditional render the gallery

**CONTEXT**: I want to create a gallery in order to show the books I have stored in my back end. For this, I fetching my books on mounting the component. The result of this is set in the variable **books**. What I'm trying to test is that, after the ajax call, the component renders the gallery with the books

**PROBLEM**: When the books variable is set, the div `<div v-else-if='books.length > 0'>SHOW GALLERY</div>` should be rendered, but the "else" div (`<div v-else class='loader'>Loading</div>`) is still rendered

The next two blocks of code are the component and the test itself:

**BookGallery.vue** (component I'm testing)

```
 <template>
      <v-content>
          <v-container fluid>

               /*** Conditional rendering: After the ajax request books > 0, so this div should be rendered ***/
              <div v-if='books.length > 0'>SHOW GALLERY</div>

              <div v-else class='loader'>Loading</div>
          </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </template>

    <script lang='ts'>
      import {Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';
      import {MyMixin} from '../mixin';

      @Component({components: {BookInformation}})
      export default class BookGallery extends MyMixin {
          public books: string[] = [];

          public async mounted() {

               /*** books is set as the result of the ajax request ***/

               this.books = (await this.$http.get(this.host + '/books')).data;
          }
      }
    </script>

    <style scoped lang='scss'></style>
```

**TEST**

```
    @test
    public async 'after calling the books, the gallery show all of them'() {

        /*** MOCKING THE RESPONSE ***/
        TestCase.OK_200({
            books: [
                { uri: 'img/covers/1.jpg', title: 'El Prinicipito'},
                { uri: 'img/covers/2.jpeg', title: 'The Lord of the Rings'},
            ],
        });


        /*** MOUNTING MY COMPONENT ***/
        const wrapper = TestCase.shallowMount(BookGallery);


        /** ASSERTING **/
        await flushPromises().then(() => {

            /**  the first "expect" passes, so books > 0 = true **/
            expect(wrapper.vm.$data.books).to.eqls({
                books: [
                    { uri: 'img/covers/1.jpg', title: 'El Prinicipito'},
                    { uri: 'img/covers/2.jpeg', title: 'The Lord of the Rings'},
                ],
            });

            /** This is failing. The application should read 'SHOW GALLERY' when books > 0 (something tested in the previous assert), as explained in the first comment of the component's template, but is not updating the dom, only the data **/
            see('SHOW GALLERY');
        });
    }
```

> **The QUIESTION**: How can I update my DOM for my very last assert -`see("SHOW GALLERY")`-?

**UPDATE**

**see Function**
The function only searches for a HTML element in the wrapper that vue-test-utils is using for mounting the application. In this case, as I have left it null, it is searching the text "SHOW GALLERY" over the whole HTML file

```
export const see = (text: string, selector?: string) => {
    const wrap = selector ? wrapper.find(selector) : wrapper;

    expect(wrap.html()).contains(text);
};
```

Comment: did you try `wrapper.update()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to force the update, but I have the feeling it only updates the data again, no idea how to update the render function

Comment: What is the `see` function doing? Is that a common way to assert something in a library not mentioned here?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'll edit the post

Comment: I had very similar problem and just solved it using `mount` instead of `shallowMount`. Try it.
Another potential problem:
`@Component({components: {BookInformation}})` in BookGallery.vue - you are not using `BookInformation` anywhere.

Answer (score 20):

I just solved a similar problem, using shallowMount and its `sync: false` option.

This deactivates sync rendering, requiring you to give the renderer some time to perform its job (`await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()`) where needed.
Once this done, the component was re-rendered based on my reactive data, as expected.

Comment: I'm getting "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function" when adding await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() to my specs.

Comment: Then make your function `async`, or use `$nextTick()`'s more traditional promise syntax: `wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(() => { /* your code goes here */ }`

Comment: await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() worked for me without setting sync to false

Comment: Is this mentioned somewhere in the doc?

Comment: @XiaoPeng-ZenUML.com I don't know  about the doc, but it's explained here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1137

Answer (score 16):

I ran into very similar problem and solved it with `await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();` before assertion that failed. This forces Vue to update view.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, the above answer worked

Comment: insure that you are using `await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();`

that worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Initially Vue Test Utils run updates synchronously. But later they removed sync mode. [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1137) they explain reasons and show how to write tests:

> Test code will change from this:
>
> ```
> it('render text', (done) => {
>     const wrapper = mount(TestComponent)
>     wrapper.trigger('click')
>     wrapper.text().toContain('some text')
> })
> ```
>
> To this:
>
> ```
> it('render text', async () => {
>     const wrapper = mount(TestComponent)
>     wrapper.trigger('click')
>     await Vue.nextTick()
>     wrapper.text().toContain('some text')
> })
> ```

So, to fix your issue you need to add `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` before assertion `see('SHOW GALLERY');`

Comment: From where coming the `Vue` var ?

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo `import Vue from 'vue'` or you can also use the method from the wrapper:  `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()`. Or it's also possible just await the trigger itself: `await wrapper.trigger('click')` See the docs: https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-asynchronous-behavior

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where child components markup was not rendered on mount and based on the other answers the following worked for me:

```js
test('it works as expected', async () => {
  const wrapper = await mount(TestComponent);
  //expect(...)
});
```